# Is there a better way to add attribute field into AST in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

At first, I have a original AST definition like this:

```
data Expr = LitI Int | LitB Bool | Add Expr Expr
```

And I want to generalize it so that each AST node can contains some extra attributes:

```
data Expr a = LitI Int a | LitB Bool a | Add (Expr a) (Expr a) a
```

In this way, we can easily attach attribute into each node of the AST:

```
type ExprWithType = Expr TypeRep
type ExprWithSize = Expr Int
```

But this solution makes it hard to visit the attribute field, we must use pattern matching and process it case by case:

```
attribute :: Expr a -> a
attribute e = case e of
    LitI _ a -> a
    LitB _ a -> a
    Add _ _ a -> a
```

We can image that if we can define our AST via a product type of the original AST and the type variable indicating attribute:

```
type ExprWithType = (Expr, TypeRep)
type ExprWithSize = (Expr, Int)
```

Then we can simplify the attribute visiting function like this:

```
attribute = snd
```

But we know that, the attribute from the outmost product type will not recursively appears in the subtrees.

So, is there a better solution for this problem?

Generally speaking, When we want to extract common field of different cases of a recursive sum type, we met this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "lift" the type of the `Expr` for example like:

```
data Expr e = LitI Int | LitB Bool | Add e e
```

Now we can define a data type like:

```
data ExprAttr a = ExprAttr {
    expression :: Expr (ExprAttr a),
    attribute :: a
  }
```

So here the `ExprAttr` has two parameters, the `expression`, which is thus an `Expr`ession that has `ExprAttr a`s in the tree, and `attribute` which is an `a`.

You can thus process `ExprAttr`s, which is an AST of `ExprAttr`s. If you want to use a "simple" AST, you can define a type like:

```
newtype SimExpr = SimExpr (Expr SimExpr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [`Cofree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html) where `f` will be your recursive data type after abstracting the concept of recursion as an [f-algebra](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras) and `a` will be the type of your annotation.

Nate Faubion gave a very accesible talk about this and similar approaches and you can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKkxmVFcd74